# Rendered view different than camera view in Viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I am new to blender and I have been learning from Andrew Price's youtube beginner tutorial series. So I am making a donut and coffee and I have enabled Lock Camera to View but my final render is different than the camera view in Viewport[image: The camera view in Viewport][image: Final image rendered in separate window].

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have a keyframe on the timeline on frame 2, maybe on that keyframe you staged the camera in a different way than frame 0 or 1. Try to remove all keyframes from the timeline, then go to frame 1 adjust the camera in the way you want and render (be sure you are at frame 1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. Worked like a charm !!!

Comment: I tried this, but did not work.  I had 8 keyframes and cleared all of it.  I also deleted the current camera and added a new camera.  Then, added one keyframe at frame 1.  on rendering, the view was still different from the viewport's view.